# replace contents of all tags in xml in python with beautifulsoup

Tags: xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, timedelta, python-datetime

**Here is the xml/kml file that I want to change:** http://pastebin.com/HNwzLppa

**The problem I am trying to solve:** We have a kml file generated by data in a log file. The data sometimes has a time drift from GMT. (We are addressing this.) We have no control over the data that that process uses to generate the kml otherwise this whole exercise would be moot. We have written a script that checks to see the drift from GMT.

**What I want to accomplish:**  Use the script we have alreaady written to input the hours, minutes and seconds differnce into this script. Find all the `<timestamp>` tags and extract the `datetime` and do a `timedelta` and write back the new timestamp, and then save the file.

**What I have done so far:**

```
import datetime
import time
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Open the KML file.
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('doc.kml'), "xml")

#Take keyboard input on hours minutes and seconds offset
hdata = raw_input("How many hours off is the file: ")
mdata = raw_input("How many minutes off is the file: ")
sdata = raw_input("How many seconds off is the file: ")

#Convert string to float for use in timedelta.
h = float(hdata)
m = float(mdata)
s = float(sdata)

#Find the timestamp tags in the file. In this case just the first 68.
times = soup('timestamp', limit=68)

#Loop thru the tags.
for time in times:  
timestring = time.text[8:27]
newdate = (datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + datetime.timedelta(hours= h, minutes = m, seconds = s))
times.replaceWith()

#Print to output the contents of the file.
print(soup.prettify())
```

**The error I am getting:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\timeshift.py", line 27, in <module>
times.replaceWith()
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'replaceWith'
```

My question is how do I do what I am trying to do and after the prettify statement write the file to disk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I change the `times.replaceWith()` to `time.replaceWith(newdate)` and got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\timeshift.py", line 27, in <module>
    timestring.replaceWith(newdate)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'replaceWith'. Now what?

Comment: `timestring` is not the same thing as `time`.

Comment: Sorry I did use the `timestring.replaceWith(newdate)`. When I do `time.replaceWith(newdate)` I get:                                    File ".\timeshift.py", line 27, in <module>
    time.replaceWith(newdate)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 213, in replace_with
    old_parent.insert(my_index, replace_with)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 293, in insert
    new_child.parent = self
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'parent'

Comment: I've provided you with a working solution below; you want to replace the text node contained *in* the tag, not the tag itself, and then you want to first turn your `datetime` object back into a string.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I am new at Python and got stumped and none of the BeautifulSoup docs covered this kind of thing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to replace the *`times` result set* (with `s`), not the single `time` tag (no `s`).

However, you probably don't want to replace the tag; you want to replace the *text in the tag*:

```
for time in times:  
    timestring = time.text[8:27]
    newdate = (datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") +
               datetime.timedelta(hours= h, minutes = m, seconds = s))
    newstring = soup.new_string(time.text[:8] + 
        newdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + time.text[27:])
    time.string.replaceWith(newstring)
```

This creates a new `NavigableString` object with `soup.new_string()`, and replaces the original string child node on `time`.

Comment: When I try to put a `soup.write()` with any argument, I get an error. How do i write this back to disk?

Comment: @technocon: [How to save back changes made to a HTML file using BeautifulSoup in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14369447)